# Play FakeMultipartRequest unexpected end of input

Tags: scala, testing, multipart, playframework-2.5

I am breaking my head with testing my controller.

I have the following test code that tests a simple csv upload, The file exists and the endpoint work when I try to upload from some simple rest client like postmen

I am getting: 400 unexpected end of input.

Tried everything i can think of. Thanks

> ```
>     val controller = application.injector.instanceOf[MyController]
>     val file = play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile(FileUtils.toFile(getClass.getResource(MyCSV)))
>     val data = new MultipartFormData(Map(), List(
>       FilePart("file", "sample.csv", Some("application/csv"), file)
>     ), List())
>     def fakeMultipartRequest: FakeRequest[AnyContentAsMultipartFormData] = FakeRequest(HttpVerbs.POST, "/upload")
>       .withHeaders(("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=***boundry***"))
>       .withMultipartFormDataBody(data)  
>     val result = call(controller.upload(), fakeMultipartRequest)
>     val str = contentAsString(result)
>     status(result) shouldBe OK
> ```

and my controller is simple:

```
def upload() = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request => ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. In my case it was due to some custom Filter that reads token from request and parses it as json. Take a look at Filters that you use

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found out that you need to set the `dataParts` property of `MultipartFormData`:

```
val data = new MultipartFormData(Map("" -> Seq("dummydata")), List(
  FilePart("file", "sample.csv", Some("application/csv"), file)
), List())
```

This way I also didn't have to set the content-type/boundary header.